# "Invalid Column Name" - Query Fails

Tags: t-sql, select, failover

I have a rather large query that I run on a particular database. What this query does is select specific columns from specific tables and dumps them into a new table. The new table is used and modified later in the query.

The problem I'm running into is, while the databases are supposedly from the same program, one database might have columns email1, email2, and email3 but the next one might only have email1. Because email1-3 are used as a part of the select statement, when one of these columns is missing, that portion fails and the table never gets created.

I'm still very much new to this so my question may be simple or silly but is there any way to save the results when a column is missing like this? I could just as easily just remove the columns that are missing from the query and run it again but I'm wondering if there is a more correct way to do this?

Example:

```
SELECT  Customer.[Name], 
    Customer.AcctKey, 
    SUBSTRING(Customer.LastName,1,25) AS [Last Name], 
    SUBSTRING(Customer.FirstName,1,25) AS [First Name], 
    Customer.Add1 AS Address, 
    Customer.Add2 AS Address2, 
    Customer.City, 
    Customer.State,                 
    Customer.Zip, 
    Location.Add1 AS [Ship Address], 
    Location.Add2 AS [Ship Address2], 
    Location.City AS [Ship City], 
    Location.State AS [Ship State], 
    Location.Zip AS [Ship Zip], 
    Customer.Phone1 AS Phone, 
    Customer.Phone2 AS [Alt Phone],
    Customer.Phone3 AS [Cell Phone],
    Customer.Phone4 AS Fax, 
    Customer.lblPhone1, 
    Customer.lblPhone2, 
    Customer.lblPhone3, 
    Customer.lblPhone4, 
    Customer.Terms, 
    Customer.[Key] AS [Account Number], 
    Location.Notes, 
    Location.TaxCode AS [Tax Item], 
    Location.Zone AS [Map Code], 
    Location.Contact, 
    Location.Email, 
    Location.Email6, --Fails because column(s) Email2-6
    Location.Email5, --don't exist in this database
    Location.Email4, --but they might in another
    Location.Email3, --and I'd like to get the data
    Location.Email2, --if they do
    Location.Phone6, 
    Location.Phone5

INTO [01Parents]
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Location ON Customer.[Key] = Location.[Key]
```

Comment: email1, email2, email3....sounds like a really bad design. These should be rows, not columns.

Comment: I won't disagree with you there. We get databases from different software, sometimes they are access DB's, sometimes SQL Server, sometimes just Excel spreadsheets, and we move the data into an SQL database for use with our software. This particular one is an SQL database but it is made very poorly (e.g. There's a Name field where the first, middle, last, and/or Company Name goes). What makes it worse is this other software doesn't restrict how you use its fields. You could fill in it's email3 field with a bunch of numbers and never use email1.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get problem right. Can you post example queries?

Comment: You could check for field names via `sys.columns` and then build a SQL statement and execute it. Let me know if this is something that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL, N'') + CASE WHEN @SQL IS NULL THEN c.name ELSE N', ' + c.name END
FROM
    sys.columns AS c INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON
            c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    o.name = @table
ORDER BY
    c.column_id

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + @SQL +  N' INTO 01Parents FROM Customer INNER JOIN ON Customer.[Key] = Location.[Key]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if this worked for you. (Or if you tried it.)